# Evaluating a definite integral using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx$ using the residues.

I am not really sure what contour I should be considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite your integral in terms of trig functions. Your integral is equal to
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2 t}{1+\sin^2 t}dt
$$

Comment: and then am guessing I should use the exponential formulae for both sin and cos. Thanks :)

Comment: @debanjana sounds right!

Comment: I think we try to compute $I+\pi = I+ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 t} dt$ and then apply the formula for exponential it becomes easier!

Comment: I don't think this works. Note that the given equation is equivalent to 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\cos t\over 1+\sin^2 t}\ dt$$
But
$$-\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\cos t\over 1+\sin^2 t}\ dt = \int^{3\pi/2}_{\pi/2}{\cos t\over 1+\sin^2t}\ dt$$
So, changing $\sin$ and $\cos$ to $z$ functions, $\int_{|z| =1} = 0$. Residue theorem is not working.